# Estrutura de busca de controller mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma aplicação normal em mvc 5 e gostaria de alterar a convenção básica de pastas para controllers/views.

Por exemplo:

- /Controllers/**Admin**/Controller1.cs
- /Controllers/**Admin**/Controller2.cs

e quando eu crio views, sigo a convenção existente:

- /Views/Controller1/Index.cshtml
- /Views/Controller2/Index.cshtml

O problema é o seguinte: no action, quando eu uso a opção "*Go To View*" ele encontra corretamente a view, mas o inverno não funciona. Na view, quando uso a opção "*Go To Controller*" recebo a mensagem "*Unable to find a matching controller*".

Não posso cogitar o uso de areas pq a próxima versão do mvc virá sem ela.

Existe alguma solução pra isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não.

O Visual Studio supõe que todos os seus *Controllers* estão na estrutura padrão de projeto, ou seja, logo abaixo do diretório *Controllers*.

Não há maneira de mudar este comportamento, até porque *Views* não fazem referência diretamente a *Controllers*. O que o Visual Studio faz é examinar o diretório em que essas *Views* estão e deduzir qual o *Controller* delas.

Repare que usando o atalho em `~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml`, você terá a mesma mensagem. E isto está correto, porque arquivos de Layout não pertencem a *Controller* algum.

Comment: É uma pena... Achei que houvesse alguma forma de simular esse mecanismo como ocorre usando o mecanismo de areas pelo menos. Sabe se é possível?

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa antes de responder e não achei nada, infelizmente.